# ¿Cómo cambiar de campo automáticamente al diligenciar un formulario tkinter con pistola lectora de barras?

Tags: python-3.x, tkinter

Tengo un formulario de **tkinter** con los campos **Responsable**, **Cliente** y **Caja** tipo Entry, deseo diligenciarlo con una pistola lectora de códigos de barras que cuando registre el **responsable** me envié al campo **cliente** automáticamente y luego de **cliente** al campo **Caja**, mediante un **Tab** automático luego del registro.

Agradezco sus aportes.

Comment: Cuando presiona Tab dentro del Entry, se mueve automáticamente al siguiente Entry (en el orden en que se crearon los widgets). Cuando lee datos usando una pistola lectora, ¿no ocurre la transición?

Comment: "Cuando lee datos usando una pistola lectora, ¿no ocurre la transición? " Exacto, la transición no ocurre por lo que requiero que luego del registro en el Entry se genere un Tab automático para evitar presionarlo con el teclado y desplazarme por el formulario con la pistola lectora luego de cada registro.

Comment: ¿Cómo se separan los diferentes campos al leer? ¿Usa salto de línea (Enter) o algo más?

Comment: Los registros en los campos los capturo en variables que luego van a un dataframe, en cada campo va un registro y actualmente no uso ningún salto de línea.

Comment: Tal vez no lo puse de esa manera. ¿De qué forma obtienes datos de una pistola lectora?

Comment: Los datos se obtienen de códigos de barras, similar a los supermercados o tiendas de abarrotes.

Comment: Quiero decir, ¿cómo son los datos (texto) codificados por estos códigos de barras? ¿Cómo se separan los diferentes campos de datos?

Comment: Correctamente entiendo que una pistola lectora es un dispositivo [HID](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/USB_human_interface_device_class) que, al leer un código de barras, imprime el texto en un campo de texto, como si se hubiera ingresado desde el teclado? Para responder, debe saber cómo se ve el texto que emite el lector.

Comment: "¿cómo son los datos (texto) codificados por estos códigos de barras?" Los datos son nombres de personas ejemplo **"CARLOS.RAMIREZ"**, y ciudades ejemplo **"MEDELLIN"**, respecto a la codificación no tengo mucha información ya que los códigos ya vienen impresos.

Comment: El texto impreso se ve en los Entry de tkinter tal cuál como los ejemplos que menciono anteriormente y la variable que los captura los imprime como strings.